# What is the correct way to change order status in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-status, service-contract

After placing an order, my module calls an external API.

If success from external API, I need to update the order status.

I know how to update status in Magento 1 but how do you do this in Magento 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::get` and `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::save`. This is public API of sales module and after future Magento releases will not change, so your custom module will not be broken.

Magento 1 style (manipulations with models an resource models directly from third party modules) should not be used in case when suitable public API is available (such classes/methods are marked with `@api` tag). Such approach will lead to custom module being broken after the next Magento 2 releases.

Comment: thanks for your response.  Sorry, not sure if I was clear. I'm calling the external API within a custom Magento module (app/code/mymodule) and after return from the call I update the order status in the custom Magento module.  With this approach ok to still call  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()?  Also, after getting instance of OM, I'm using using "load()" method but "save" method is not found. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Object manager should not be used directly, inject dependencies via construct. Also take a look at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html